# SQL query ERROR: I am putting a CASE expression to select date to get the results (Count) as morning, evening and night shifts

Tags: sql, datetime, time, case

I want to select datetime from previous 15 days and then for each day I want
to get the counts as 'night, morning, evening' wise.

Here is the code which I am trying to run to select the previous 15 days datetime from **smsOutboxHistory**  table and then apply **CASE** statement on the datetime by parting it to hour, finally applying count to get the desired result.
***But this is not working and giving me error near CASE statement***

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar(20), OH_Datetime, 101) AS Date

            CASE 
            WHEN CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar)>= 00 AND CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) <= 7 THEN COUNT(OH_Datetime) END AS Morning,
            CASE WHEN CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) >= 8 AND CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) <= 17 THEN COUNT(OH_Datetime) END AS Night,
            CASE WHEN CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) >= 18 AND CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) <= 24 THEN COUNT(OH_Datetime) END AS Evening

            FROM         dbo.smsOutboxHistory AS OH_Datetime
            WHERE     (DATEDIFF(day, OH_Datetime, GETDATE()) <= 15)
            ORDER BY Date
```

Here is another code I tried previously. I get the counts but it's in single column, however I want them as "**For each day night, morning, evening wise**"

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar(20), OH_Datetime, 101) AS DT, COUNT(*) AS SMScnts
FROM         dbo.smsOutboxHistory AS OH_Datetime
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(day, OH_Datetime, GETDATE()) <= 15)
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(20), OH_Datetime, 101), CASE WHEN CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) >= 0 AND CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) 
                      <= 8 THEN 'Night' WHEN CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) >= 8 AND CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) 
                      <= 16 THEN 'Morning' WHEN CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) >= 16 AND CAST(DATEPART(hh, OH_Datetime) AS varchar) 
                      <= 24 THEN 'Evening' END
ORDER BY DT
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why do you cast to a varchar? That cannot be compared to a number.

Comment: "It's giving me an error" - you probably need to be more specific.  [Edit] your question and copy in the actual error message

Comment: What are you aliasing your table with `dbo.smsOutboxHistory AS OH_Datetime` for? That's just confusing as you have a column with the same name.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it was relational database. I get back to stack-overflow and programming again after failing it in 2016.

Comment: @TobySpeight unfortunately, I have no access to the work anymore. But I am willing to ask interesting questions.

Answer (score 4):

You need `group by`, not `select distinct`.  And a count.  And don't convert hours to strings for comparisons.  So:

```
SELECT CAST(OH_DateTime as DATE) AS Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, OH_Datetime) >= 00 AND DATEPART(hour, OH_Datetime <= 7
               THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS Morning,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, OH_Datetime) >= 8 AND DATEPART(hour, OH_Datetime <= 17
               THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS NIGHT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, OH_Datetime) >= 18 AND DATEPART(hour, OH_Datetime <= 24
               THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS Evening
FROM  dbo.smsOutboxHistory OH_Datetime
WHERE OH_Datetime >= DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY CAST(OH_DateTime as DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(OH_DateTime as DATE);
```

Comment: `IIF` might be even better thant `CASE WHEN ..` here?

Comment: Remove the comma in WHERE OH_Datetime, >= .... And there are closing parentheses missing for the `DATEPART` functions. (And when editing already you can also remove the unnecessary table alias. :-)

Comment: @MincongHuang . . . I fail to see how a bespoke function such as `IIF()` -- which is available only in SQL Server and MS Access -- could be better than the ANSI standard method of doing the same thing.

Comment: It might be better for readability because it is shorter: here, a `CASE WHEN ...` takes 3 lines and `IIF()` takes 1. Then, it shows that this is a boolean choice. And the last thing, I agree that it is better to use ANSI standard, but the simplicity of the statement should be more priority since people are dealing with their specific database instead of applying this SQL everywhere. Do you agree with me ?